# Installing a Module on Heroku

Tags: django, module, heroku, python-imaging-library, pip

I'm deploying something that has been running on my local and realized when I deployed that the module I was using wasn't installed on Heroku, thus I was getting an error like this:

```
...
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I've tried:

```
heroku run pip install PIL
```

but I'm getting this:

```
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command
```

---

edit

So, I went to the [heroku setup](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) and mimicked the steps to install django and postgres.  Essentially, I activated the environment and then ran

```
pip install PIL
```

This seemed to be doing the trick, I got a lot of readout and then it ended with a confirmation that PIL had been installed.  But then again, it said it couldn't find PIL when I ran the new file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every command you run on Heroku is run in an isolated and ephemeral environment — any changes you make during `heroku run` are thrown away immediately when the processes completes.

To make PIL available to your application, you need to add it to `requirements.txt` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have followed http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#prerequisites and your virtualenv is loaded?

BTW, I recommend using [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead of PIL.

> Introduction
>
> The fork author's goal is to foster packaging improvements via:
>
> Publicized development and solicitation of community support.
>   Exploration of packaging problems within the fork, most noticably via
>   adding setuptools support but also via clean up & refactoring of
>   packaging code. Why a fork?
>
> PIL is currently not setuptools compatible. Please see
>   http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-August/006480.html for
>   a more detailed explanation. Also, PIL's current release/maintenance
>   schedule is not compatible with the various & frequent packaging
>   issues that have occured.

Comment: yeah, everything was working fine on heroku's side until I added a file that need PIL.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes PIL package is added in your path but it's somewhere else than in *site-packages*. In this case you will be able to just `import Image`.

To make sure try something like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
[(...), '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', (...)]
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
>>> import Image
>>> Image
<module 'Image' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc'>
```

In my applications I use code like this:

```
try:
    import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
except:
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
```

Comment: I just gave this a shot, but it still failed to find the module:              from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
ImportError: No module named PIL

Answer (score 1):

Even i was facing the same issue, I spent quite a lot of time.

#### I tried this

`heroku run pip install PIL --app=your-app`

#### error:

```
Running `pip install PIL` attached to terminal... up, run.1983
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log
```

#### But this helps like a charm :)

`heroku run pip install Pillow --app=your-app`